# Do I replicate observations to weight by population? For regression

Tags: regression, weighted-data

*Note: This question may well be a duplicate, but I don't know the language to use to find it. I have searched the site and Google but haven't seen anything that I am looking for – maybe dasymetric mapping is relevant?*

I have data census block level, but the population of these blocks vary wildly. I believe this will skew the model by making the conditions of smaller blocks more influential. A block with four people will be weighted the same as a block with four hundred people.

The way I can see to account for this is to replicate each case by the number of people in the block. Because all my variables are percentages of people or households within the block that fit a certain attribute the variables still make sense when the case is one person – the variable becomes the likelihood, given our knowledge of the block, that the person fulfills the attribute. In such an arrangement every person is represented equally, regardless of which block came from.

Is there a name and literature for this approach – or am I totally off base?

For example:

```
       pop        X1           X2
 1       3     0.714        0.799
 2       1     1            0.9  
 3       2     0.714        0.714
 4       1     0.8          0.766
```

becomes

```
       pop        X1           X2
 1       3     0.714        0.799
 2       3     0.714        0.799
 3       3     0.714        0.799
 4       1     1            0.9  
 5       2     0.714        0.714
 6       2     0.714        0.714
 7       1     0.8          0.766
```

Comment: Statistics is used to analyze the data, and cannot be used to generate data.

Comment: @a_statistician I wouldn’t be generating data... I'm essentially weighting it